# Two classes differing only in base class

Tags: python-3.x

I have come across a problem where I need two classes that will have identical implementation and the only difference between them will be different name and base class. What is a reasonable way of doing this?

One obvious solution is to violate DRY and copy the implementations like this:

```
class FooA(BaseA):
    def frobnicate(self):
        print("frob")

class FooB(BaseB):
    def frobnicate(self):
        print("frob")
```

Comment: Can you be more concrete?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE

Comment: Are you looking for a mixin? If you have `Foo` and `Bar` and a common implementation of some services in `Mixin`, you can create `class BetterFoo(Mixin, Foo)` and `BetterBar(Mixin, Bar)`. Also consider [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

Comment: Actually, a mixin is exactly what I need, it just didn't click in my head :). Thanks. Can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple inheritance to implement interfaces and common functionality in a single mixin class. Given the clear desire to `frobnicate` in many classes, just implement a frobnicator. Python builds the class from right to left so mixins are left-most.

```
class Frobnicator(object):
    def frobnicate(self):
        print("frob")

class FooA(Frobnicator, BaseA):
    pass

class FooB(Frobnicator, BaseB):
    pass
```

Note that mixins usually do not implement their own `__init__` - that's the job of the base class.